# Django form not submit and no errors thrown

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Below is my code within my views.py. I have a FormView that's being created and prepopulated just fine but when I submit it doesn't go to form_valid(), and when it goes to form_invalid() it doesn't print out any errors.

Any help is much appreciated.

views.py

```
class CleanTeamMainContactView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "cleanteams/main_contact.html"
    form_class = EditCleanTeamMainContact
    success_url = "mycleancity/index.html"

    def get_initial(self, clean_team_member):
        initial = {}

        if clean_team_member:
            clean_team = clean_team_member.clean_team
            contact_user = clean_team.contact_user

            initial['contact_first_name'] = contact_user.first_name
            initial['contact_last_name'] = contact_user.last_name
            initial['contact_email'] = contact_user.email
            initial['contact_phone'] = clean_team.contact_phone
            initial['clean_ambassadors'] = clean_team.contact_user.id
            initial['clean_team_id'] = clean_team.id

        return initial

    # Initialize the form with initial values
    def get_form(self, form_class): 
        clean_team_member = self.request.user.profile.clean_team_member

        return form_class(
            clean_team=clean_team_member.clean_team,
            initial=self.get_initial(clean_team_member)
        )

    def form_invalid(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = form

        print form.errors
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        clean_team_id = form.cleaned_data['clean_team_id']

        try:
            clean_team_member =     CleanTeamMember.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
            clean_team_member.clean_team.update_main_contact(form.cleaned_data)
        except Exception, e:
            print e

        return HttpResponseRedirect(u'/clean-team/%s' %(clean_team_id))
```

forms.py

```
class EditCleanTeamMainContact(forms.Form):
    # clean_ambassadors = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, label="Clean ambassadors")
    contact_first_name = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length = 128, min_length = 2, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}), label="First name")
    contact_last_name = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length = 128, min_length = 2, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}), label="Last name")
    contact_phone = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length = 128, min_length = 2, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'phone-number'}), label="Phone number")
    contact_email = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length = 128, min_length = 2, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}), label="Email address")
    clean_team_id = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, clean_team=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditCleanTeamMainContact, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        print clean_team
        # Prepopulate the Clean Ambassador drop down
        ctm_queryset = CleanTeamMember.objects.filter(clean_team=clean_team)
        self.fields["clean_ambassadors"] = forms.ChoiceField(label="Clean Ambassadors", widget=None, choices=[(o.user.id, str(o.user.profile.get_full_name())) for o in ctm_queryset])

        print self.fields["clean_ambassadors"].choices

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(EditCleanTeamMainContact, self).clean()

        contact_phone = cleaned_data.get("contact_phone")

        if not contact_phone:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a contact phone number")

        return cleaned_data
```

main_contact.html

```
{% extends '_public_base.html' %}

{% block title %} My Clean City - Main Contact {% endblock %}

{% block css %}
  <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/mycleancity.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="wrapper public">
  <div class="clouds"></div>

  {% include "_loggedin_navbar.html" %}

  <a href="/" class="logo"></a>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1); return false;"><div class="sign register" id="sign-go-back"></div></a>
      <div id="white-box" class="small main-contact">
          <h2>Main Contact for {{ user.profile.clean_team_member.clean_team.name }}</h2>
          <span class="subtitle">Select one of the Clean Ambassadors to set them as the primary contact. If their information is incorrect, have them update their information by logging in and going to Edit Profile.</span>

          {% if form.non_field_errors %}
            <div class="message-box error">
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            </div>
          {% endif %}

          <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.clean_team_id }}

            <table>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">{{ form.clean_ambassadors.label_tag }} {{ form.clean_ambassadors }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ form.contact_first_name.label_tag }} {{ form.contact_first_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.contact_last_name.label_tag }} {{ form.contact_last_name }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ form.contact_email.label_tag }} {{ form.contact_email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.contact_phone.label_tag }} {{ form.contact_phone }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update Main Contact" />
          </form>
      </div><!-- /#white-box -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  </div><!-- /.about -->
</div> <!-- /.wrapper -->
{% include "_footer_navbar.html" %}

{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you please post your `form`, and if it's a `ModelForm`, your `model` as well?

Comment: I've add my forms.py file

Comment: I can't find any issues in the code. Have you checked the post data to see if it's what you expected?

Comment: The issue is that it's only going to form_invalid(), with no error messages. For unfortunately I can't even check to see if the data is POSTing. Unless of course there's something I'm missing.

Comment: If it's getting inside the is_invalid function, then you're definitely doing a POST. Try printing form.data or form.cleaned_data

Comment: K, when I do "print form.data" the output is: {} When I do "print form.is_bound" it says False.

Comment: Hmm, can I see your template that renders the form?

Comment: I've added the main_contact.html file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason why the data isn't being given to the form is because you have overridden the `get_form` method without passing it the `request.POST` data. Instead of overriding that method, I think it's more appropriate to override the `get_form_kwargs` method instead.

```
class CleanTeamMainContactView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "cleanteams/main_contact.html"
    form_class = EditCleanTeamMainContact
    success_url = "mycleancity/index.html"

    def get_initial(self, clean_team_member):
        ...

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        clean_team_member = self.request.user.profile.clean_team_member
        kwargs = {
            "initial": self.get_initial(clean_team_member),
            "clean_team": clean_team_member.clean_team
        }
        if self.request.method in ("POST", "PUT"):
            kwargs.update({
                "data": self.request.POST,
                "files": self.request.FILES
            })
        return kwargs

    def form_invalid(self, form, **kwargs):
        ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
```

This should hopefully fix the empty `form.data` issue but I'm not sure if the form will still be invalid or not.